# Using SOAP WSDL with cross domain AJAX request

Tags: javascript, ajax, wsdl

I want to call a Web Service(~WSDL) from JavaScript(AJAX) but it says not allowed Access-Control-Allow-Origin. is there ant SOAP based WSDL service with Access-Control-Allow-Origin for all?

Like http://www.w3schools.com/webservices/tempconvert.asmx?op=CelsiusToFahrenheit
it is only for server side scripts not for Java Scripts. I am using [ws.js](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/webservices/library/ws-wsajax/) and i want to test with any live service as a POC.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: anything on this so far?

Comment: possible duplicate of [jquery / ajax / soap - access-control-allow-origin](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7288993/jquery-ajax-soap-access-control-allow-origin)