# jquery / ajax / soap - access-control-allow-origin

Tags: jquery, ajax, soap, post

I'm trying to access a SOAP web service using jquery / ajax and getting an access control  allow origin error:

XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://site.com/service/Service.asmx?op=LoginConsumer. Origin http://localhost:8888 is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin

Is there a way around this? Are their certain things I need to do to set this up? I've been told that there are no access controls in place yet. I'm testing from a local server (localhost).

I'm following this tutorial:

http://openlandscape.net/2009/09/25/call-soap-xm-web-services-with-jquery-ajax/

Comment: You can use proxy pattern. Check this link: http://developer.yahoo.com/javascript/howto-proxy.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be violating the [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) restriction. You cannot send AJAX requests to different domains.

Comment: That's why I'm asking if there's a way around this.

Comment: @mheavers, well, there's JSONP, but it doesn't work with POST and it most definitely it doesn't work with SOAP. Your only solution in this case is to write a bridge service on your domain which will simply delegate the call to the distant web service and then have your client script send the AJAX request to this bridge service. It's the only way.

Comment: Thanks - yeah - I've tried a proxy - haven't had much success. SOAP is a pain!

Answer (score 3):

Try creating a `fetchSoap.php` page on `localhost` that fetches the data from `site.com` and simply echos it. Then you can fetch the data from `localhost/fetchSoap.php` and you will not be violating same origin policies.

The PHP code would be (you can use any language you're currently using)

**http://localhost/FetchSOAP.php**

```
 <?php
     die( file_get_contents( 'http://site.com/PathToSoap/' ) );
 ?>
```

Comment: I don't have access to site.com - I would have to get the other party involved to create this.

Comment: Well, if it's the other way around, create a page on `localhost` to fetch the data from `site.com` - this way the JS on `localhost` can fetch the data from `localhost/fetcher.php` and not violate the policies. I've update my answer to reflect that.

Comment: Thanks - it was a good attempt, but I guess this doesn't work because the web service is expecting POST, so I guess I have to make some sort of PHP proxy. I found something here: http://www.phpclasses.org/package/6781-PHP-Generate-code-to-access-SOAP-services-from-an-WSDL.html