# XMLHttpRequest cannot load

Tags: php, javascript, apache, xmlhttprequest, cross-site

I am trying to access resourced from multiple servers using AJAX, and I am running into this problem:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://first.mydomain.com. Origin http://second.mydomain.com is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
```

With the following code

```
    for ( i in domains )
    {
        var url = 'http://'+domains[i]+'/mgmt/json/queue_status.php';
        requests[i]=new request(url);
        break;
    }

    function request(url)
    {
        var queues = {};
        http_request = new XMLHttpRequest();
        http_request.open("GET", url, true, 'username', 'password');
        http_request.onreadystatechange = function () {
            var done = 4, ok = 200;
            if (http_request.readyState == done && http_request.status == ok) {
                queues = JSON.parse(http_request.responseText);
                var queuesDiv = document.getElementById('queues');
                print_queues(queues, queuesDiv);                
            }
        }
        http_request.send(null);
    }
```

I have added the following to response page being requested.

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
```

I have tried explicitly naming the requester too with no success.

Thanks

PS: The above code I am sure ins't perfect but function fine when only trying to requests the resource of the host server.

Comment: Classic. This is happening because of the [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy)

Comment: Ok, but is there any way around this?

Comment: Yes, via JSONP callbacks and `<script>` tag injection.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1300130/explanation-and-usage-of-jsonp

Comment: OK, so far as I can tell, JSONP allows you to avoid making the XHR by making the browser get JSON from the remote resource onload, but how can I get it to run this at an interval without just crudely reloading the page.

Comment: possible duplicate of [jquery / ajax / soap - access-control-allow-origin](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7288993/jquery-ajax-soap-access-control-allow-origin)

Comment: hakre: this is probably what I am going to have to do, it is a PITA though.

Comment: Are you sure the http header is actually send? Also what happens if you temporarily remove the username and password arguments? The code looks like it should just work.

Answer (score 0):

username and password are not allowed in cross origin requests.

> Throws an INVALID_ACCESS_ERR exception if either user or password is passed as argument and the origin of url does not match the XMLHttpRequest origin.

source: http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest2/#the-open-method

Just pass the password and username as a get variable instead.